# LaTeX Two Digit Page Numbering

Tags: latex

I want to see the numbering of pages in LaTeX as follows using \thepage command: 01, 02, 03, ..., 09, 10, 11, ...etc.

So I want to have 2 digits always.

How can I achieve this smoothly?

Thank you for any help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways to achieve this. The following suffices:

```
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\ifnum\value{page}<10 0\fi\arabic{page}}
```

Reference:

- [How to convert a one digit number to a two digit number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56207/5764)